# Cannot stop the BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I know that this question has posted several times, but this situation is different. So supposed that I'm executing a method that need to iterate through several items (database rows), this require a lot of time.
Now in my `BackgroundWorker` I need in some case to stop the synchronization, in particular when the user press a button. What I did in the `_DoWork` event is this:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        LongOperation();
    }
}
```

now the problem's that when I call `worker.CancelAsync()` the `LongOperation()` continue the execution but shouldn't! 'cause the `while` have the condition of `CancellationPending`. I saw in the net that this solution is `thread-safe`, so maybe am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you expect LongOperation() will be interrupted in the _middle_ of its execution?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Exactly, I need to stop it in the middle of execution

Comment: You would have to go into LongOperation and exit any loops you have in there.

Comment: @LarsTech Uhm there is a lot of loop, in this case what do you suggest?

Comment: That's where you have to check if the worker is to be canceled and exit the  function.

Comment: @LarsTech Got it, but when I'm in this condition `if(worker.CancellationPending)` what I need to do, I mean, I've no `e.Cancel`

Comment: You can make `LongOperation()` a boolean function, return false if it was canceled, then in your while loop, see if it's false, in which case, exit that while loop.

Comment: @IlDrugo Then you should pass `worker` to `LongOperation()` where you will check for `worker.CancellationPending`. There you have to check - sometimes - for its status. Alternatives (separate thread where you call `Thread.Abort()`) are even uglier (and your operation may stop in any moment, even leaving application in an inconsistent state)

Comment: Ok I passed to `LongOperation` the `BackgroundWorker` and the argument `DoWorkEventArgs`, so the in the condition pending when I set: `e.Cancel = true;` this doesn't stop the `Background`, why? @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: `worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation=true;` is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is the following structure

```
private void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    worker=new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation=true;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted+=Bk_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.DoWork+=Bk_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    worker.CancelAsync();
}

void ReallyReallyLongOperation(BackgroundWorker worker)
{
    ...within a loop
    if(worker.CancellationPending) 
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void Bk_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ReallyReallyLongOperation(worker);
    if(worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void Bk_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!e.Cancelled)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the `LongOperation()` continue the execution but shouldn't! 'cause the `while` have the condition of `CancellationPending`.

No, it should continue execution! You are completely wrong with understanding of the `while` check. It does not check every second for the cancellation, it does the check only before starting the `LongOperation`!

So the only thing you can do in such situation is to check the `worker.CancellationPending` property **inside** the `LongOperation` method, not outside of it.